# TwilioQuest - The Ducktypium Classess JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twilio

I was just trying to complete a challenge on https://www.twilio.com/quest.

The questions in this game are:

#### The Ducktypium Classess

In your code folder, create a file named  `ducktypium.js`. Inside of it, create a class called  `Ducktypium`. The constructor should take a single string argument, a crystal color, and store that data in an instance variable named  `color`. The  **color can only be  `red`,  `blue`, or  `yellow`**. The constructor should  [throw an error](https://javascript.info/try-catch#throwing-our-own-errors)  if the argument is any other string.

When the class is created, it should  **also define a property**  called  `calibrationSequence`  that is initally set to be an  **empty array**.

The Ducktypium class must implement two instance methods:  `refract`  and  `calibrate`. Each of these functions will be described below.

#### The Refract Method

One of the required methods describes the refractive properties of ducktypium when it is exposed to colored light.

The  `refract`  method must take a single string argument, which must be one of  `red`,  `blue`, or  `yellow`. The method should  [throw an error](https://javascript.info/try-catch#throwing-our-own-errors)  if the argument is any other string, just like the constructor. This function should  **return a single string**, which is the color produced by the combination of the instance's  `color`  property and the color passed in to the  `refract`  function.

- If the instance's  `color`  property is the same as the argument passed in, return that value
- If the combination of colors is different, it should return a string which is the combination of those two  [primary colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_color).

For reference, primary colors combine in the following ways:

- red  +  blue  =  purple
- red  +  yellow  =  orange
- yellow  +  blue  =  green

#### The Calibrate Method

The other required method creates a calibration sequence required to stabilize a ducktypium crystal.

The  `calibrate`  method takes a single argument, an array of numbers. With this input array, you must do the following:

- Sort the numbers from smallest to largest
- Multiply each number in the array by  `3`
- Assign the resulting array to the  `Ducktypium`  instance's  `calibrationSequence`variable.

### My Code

```js
const VALID_COLORS = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];

class Ducktypium {
  constructor(color) {
    if (!VALID_COLORS.includes(color)) {
      throw new TypeError("Color must be red, yellow, or blue!");
    }

    this.color = color;
    this.calibrationSequence = [];
  }

  refract(pickColor) {

    if (!VALID_COLORS.includes(pickColor)) {
      throw new TypeError("Color must be red, yellow, or blue!");
    } else if (this.color == "red" && pickColor == "blue") {
      return "purple";
    } else if (this.color == "red" && pickColor == "yellow") {
      return "orange";
    } else if (this.color == "yellow" && pickColor == "blue") {
      return "green";
    } else {
      return this.color;
    }

  }

  calibrate(arrayOfNumber) {
    let currentArray = arrayOfNumber.sort();

    currentArray.forEach(item => {
      let multiply = item * 3;
      this.calibrationSequence.push(multiply);
    });
  }
}

try {
  const badColor = new Ducktypium('pink');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Color must be red, yellow, or blue!');
}

const dt = new Ducktypium('red');

console.log(dt.color); // prints 'red'

console.log(dt.refract('blue')); // prints 'purple'
console.log(dt.refract('red')); // prints 'red'

dt.calibrate([3, 5, 1]);

console.log(dt.calibrationSequence); // prints [3, 9, 15]
```

The code I wrote runs perfectly, according to the game's question. But when submitted it always appears like this:

*The refract method should return the color you get when its "color" property is concatenated with other primary colors. Look at the color combinations in the "Purpose" tab.*

Even if I didn't use try / catch, can anyone see where I went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not accounted for all combinations in the `refract` method. You've only done eg `blue+red` but not `red+blue`.

Can I suggest you write 3 boolean methods like

```
const mixPurple = (a,b) =>  (a == 'red' && b == 'blue') || (a == 'blue' && b == 'red');
const mixOrange = (a,b) => ...;
const mixGreen = (a,b) => ...;
```

And then your code does stay fairly similar

```
refract(pickColor) {

    if (!VALID_COLORS.includes(pickColor)) {
      throw new TypeError("Color must be red, yellow, or blue!");
    } else if (mixPurple(this.color,pickColor)) {
      return "purple";
    } else if (mixOrange(this.color,pickColor)) {
      return "orange";
    } else if (mixGreen(this.color,pickColor)) {
      return "green";
    } else {
      return this.color;
    }

  }
```

As it reduces all the combinations to just 3 branches and is easy to read

Comment: Wow, the code can be submitted. Thanks for your reply :).

Comment: @TommyPratama I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 0):

Just added another OR and it passed

```
    refract(refColor){
        if (this.color==="red" && refColor === "blue" || this.color==="blue" && refColor === "red"){
            return "purple"
        } else if (this.color==="red" && refColor === "yellow" || this.color==="yellow" && refColor === "red"){
            return "orange"
        }  else if (this.color==="yellow" && refColor === "blue" || this.color==="blue" && refColor === "yellow"){
            return "green"
        }   else if (this.color===refColor){
            return this.color}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better and clean solution to the question without doing too much if-else.

```
class Ducktypium {
  constructor(color) {
    this.checkColor(color);

    this.color = color;
    this.calibrationSequence = [];
  }

  checkColor(color) {
    if (!["red", "blue", "yellow"].includes(color)) {
      throw new Error("Color must be red, yellow, or blue!");
    }
  }

  combinations(colors) {
    if (colors.includes("red") && colors.includes("blue")) return "purple";
    if (colors.includes("red") && colors.includes("yellow")) return "orange";
    if (colors.includes("yellow") && colors.includes("blue")) return "green";
  }

  refract(color) {
    this.checkColor(color);

    if (this.color === color) return color;

    return this.combinations([this.color, color]);
  }

  calibrate(nums) {
    this.calibrationSequence = nums
      .map((num) => num * 3)
      .sort((a, b) => (a < b ? -1 : 1));
  }
}
```